# Not able to read raw XML into Spring Boot app

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot

I am working on a Spring Boot project and i have a requirement where in I want to read a raw xml into the application and parse that xml using parser to convert into domain object. The xml that I have is a plain xml without any namespaces or schemas. below is my xml format

```
<?xml version ="1.0" ?>
 <applications>
 <state>xyz</state>
 <app name="PROJECTx">
 <catids>
 <catid>1</catid>
 <catid>2</catid>
 </catids>
 <cys>
 <mxvalue>1000</mxvalue>
 <mnvalue>0.01</mnvalue>
 <activity>ACTIVE</activity>
 </cys>
 </app>
 </applications>
```

I am planning a normal DOM Parser API in my boot app to read this xml and convert the values into domain objects.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.test")
@ImportResource("applications.xml")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

I tried using the @ImportResource annotation to read this xml but I get the error below on spring boot start up.

```
 Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'applications'.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1900) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
```

Looks like the **@ImportResource("applications.xml")** is expecting some namespace and schemas.

Can someone help me with this and let me know is this is possible in SpringBoot application and how can I do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your XML is missing the namespace declarations. Any web search should find you lots of examples. Down-vote for lack of research.

Comment: @Andreas this is the xml that I need to work with. its a raw xml without any namespaces as I have already said. any ideas

Comment: @Andreas do you mean that I will need to add namespaces to this xml myself. well I have this contract that I need to work with.

Comment: [`@ImportResource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ImportResource.html) is for importing a Spring `<beans/>` XML file. See javadoc. *That* is configuration file, not a bean definition file. I think you are look for [`@PropertySource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html).

Comment: PropertySource annotation is for using property files and not xml files.

Comment: `@ImportResource` is for importing Spring context xml files. It isn't for importing/reading arbitrary xml files. If you want to use a parser then use a parser and read it yourself.

Comment: If the XML file is not a Spring `<beans/>` file (which `@ImportResource` can load), and is not an application properties file (which `@PropertySource` can load), what is it? Or asked another way: How did you envision your code to gain access to the loaded content?

Answer (score 1):

You should use JAXB annotations on your domain object.  Then in a spring boot @Configuration class you could create a JAXBContext and unmarshall the xml into your domain object.  A simple jaxb tutorial can be seen at http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, you many not want to use application.xml if it is in your classpath (or the same dir as the jar, or conf dir).

application